# The release management server is not currently available

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, ms-release-management

I am getting a warning message popup, when i open release management client. Please see the warning screen below.

[image]

Window is getting closed, when i clicked OK...!!

The console log is showing below.

```
8/5/2014 11:15:39 AM - Error - (4588, 7980) - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.: \r\n\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.PlatformHttpClient.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndGetAsyncMemoryStreamFromResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndDownloadString(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClient.EndPost(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.HttpRequestor.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetPostCaller>b__0(String url, String body)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.BaseConfigurationServiceProxy.<GetUserByUserName>b__0(String s)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.ConfigurationServiceUserNameRetriever.GetUserByUserName(String userName, Func`2 retriever, Func`1 dbAccessor)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.ConfigurationServiceRestProxy.<.ctor>b__0(String userName, Func`2 retriever)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.BaseConfigurationServiceProxy.GetUserByUserName(String userName)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.Console.App.HandleServerAndCurrentUserValidation(Action`1 notFound, IConfigurationService configurationServiceInstance)
 8/5/2014 11:15:39 AM - Error - (4588, 7980) - Error communicating to the web server URL: HTTP://win-uiklr7ql4rk:1000/account/releaseManagementService/_apis/releaseManagement/
```

I am doing R&D on RM. This is now a road blocking issue for me. Kindly help me to move further.

Comment: Connecting RM for the first time can be quite challenging. I wrote a blog post with some of the things I discovered when connecting both clients and deployment agents: http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2014/07/connecting-release-management-clients.html Are you behind a proxy? Have you setup the Credential Manager?

Comment: Can you connect to the web client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with "ReleaseManagement" DB connectivity. Due to some reason,  'SQL server' service was not running on the server where RM DB resides. When I started the service, RM Client is working fine....!